# How to return a list of tokens using string as an argument

Tags: python, string, list, split, token

I want to create a Python program to with function that gives token('Hello, World!') == ['hello', 'world'], but my result gives ['hello,', 'world']. What is going on?

```
import string
def token(text):
    list=[]
    text = text.lower()
    new_string = text.split()
    for x in new_string: 
        list.append(x)
        
  
return list
```

token('Hello, World!')

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
def token(text):
    list=[]
    text = text.lower()
    new_string = text.split(',')
    for x in new_string: 
        list.append(x.strip())
    return list

print(token("Hello, World!")) #==> ['hello', 'world!']
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you had issue with you return statement indentation, but i can give you advice in a better way using list comprenesion, also its not a good practice to use the saved keyword `list`:

```
def token(text):
    return [x.strip() for x in text.lower().split(',')]

print(token("yOu, wElcome")) #==> ['you', 'welcome']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is have text.split(','), so that way you split the text wrt ','. Also, you may want to indent the last line, else it will not be part of your function. Here is what I did:

```
import string
def token(text):
    list=[]
    text = text.lower()
    new_string = text.split()
    for x in new_string: 
        list.append(x)
        
  
    return list
    
print(token('Hello,World!'))  # ['hello,world!']
```